# Integer Partitions of $~n~$ with restrictions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Provide a generic formula for the number of partitions of an even number $~n~$ where one part has even value and another part also has even value.

Is there some way to approach this problem that uses Generating Functions?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. The generating function of the number of partitions with at least two even parts is
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^k}-\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^{2k-1}}=x^4+x^5+3x^6+4x^7+8x^8+11x^9+\dots$$

Comment: @gmn_1450 Any feedback from your side?